# How to actually start a disk wipe with nwipe?

Tags: 18.04, disk

So, I recently installed nwipe to clear out some disks.

On ubuntu bionic, the interface lets me select disks, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to actually start the wipe (besides calling it with `--autonuke`)

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the screen, it shows S=Start.

This will sound dumb, but press SHIFT-"S", not just "s". I infer this is a precaution to avoid wiping drives by accident.